# What does this construction mean, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, redcloth

The method below exists in the Redcloth gem.

My question is: what does the construction "`to(RedCloth::Formatters::HTML)`" mean? "to" isn't a method in the class, nor in the superclass (which is String class).

```
def to_html( *rules )
  apply_rules(rules)
  to(RedCloth::Formatters::HTML)
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you search the entire RedCloth source for `def to`, besides finding a couple of methods that start with `to`, you'll also find the exact method `to` in `ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_scan.rb.rl`.

There's two things that happen here. First, this file is preprocessed by [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/). But for this question, you may safely ignore this fact and read past the weird syntax in that file. Focus on the Ruby bits.

Second, the class `RedCloth::TextileDoc` is *reopend* here. That means the class in this file and in `lib/redcloth/textile_doc.rb` are the same. So the `to` instance method will be available to the piece of code you quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's defined at in http://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/master/ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_scan.c.rl at line 200 and attached to the class at 221.

`to(RedCloth::Formatters::HTML)` is just calling the #to method and passing in the class of the formatter (the second argument in the redcloth_to C method; the first must always be `self`).

Answer (score -1):

Could be it's defined on Object or in Kernel module.

EDIT: it's not. It's defined on line 220 of this file http://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/master/ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_scan.c.rl